# Spring MVC unit test. Spring Boot Application eads wrong configuration

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I have some problem with configuration my unit test. I have mock-test class configuration:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestContext {

    @Bean
//    @Qualifier("userTestServiceImplWithMongoDB")
    public UserService userService() {
        return Mockito.mock(UserService.class, "userServiceImplWithMongoDB");
    }

    @Bean
//    @Qualifier("taskTestServiceImplWithMongoDB")
    public TaskService taskService() {
        return Mockito.mock(TaskService.class, "taskServiceImplWithMongoDB");
    }
}
```

This file is in src/test/java directory. I start my application with class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(Application.class);
  }
}
```

My problem is that application starts with wrong configuration - this one from my test config class.
I use MongoDB repositories and I have service layer using thats repositories.

I followed this instructions: [Some tutorial](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-configuration/).

I am new to Spring, do you know what I can do to fox it?

Have a nice day :)

Comment: how do you start your application ? what are the packages for "Application" and "TestContext"

Comment: Are you having an error when launching the app OR launching a unit test ?

Comment: please post your unit test that is failing too

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are following is not for **spring**, not **spring-boot**. It is still a good tutorial to use MockMvc, however it does not cover how to load the context through spring-boot.

Check this to setup a unit test with Spring-Boot: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class YourTest {
   ...
}
```